# mootools.swiff : loaderInfo never completes

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, mootools

[EDIT 07-22-2010] removed deoms from my site[/EDIT]
[EDIT 08-26-2009] added really weird issue to the bottom of question[/EDIT]
Hi everyone
I'm trying to get going with the mootools swiff thing and I seem not to get the loaderInfo.COMPLETE event in flash.
more precisely a dynamically loaded swf never loads completely, while a static one does. Here is relevant code of my document class in flash (AS3).

use firefox + firebug to see the traces

```
package pt.classes{
    import flash.display.MovieClip
    import flash.display.LoaderInfo
    import flash.external.*
    import flash.events.Event
    import flash.events.ProgressEvent
    import flash.events.IOErrorEvent
    import flash.events.HTTPStatusEvent
    import pt.utils.myTrace
    import pt.testTrace
    import pt.classes.Episode
    
    public class Main extends MovieClip{
        include "../testTrace.as";//this is a trace() implementation that redirects traces to the firebug console
        public function Main(){
            trace ("constructor for "+ this);
            var l_this:Main = this;
            loaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loaderComplete);
            loaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.INIT, function(_e:Event){trace("init for "+ l_this)});
            loaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.OPEN, function(_e:Event){trace("open for "+ l_this)});
            loaderInfo.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, function(_e:ProgressEvent){trace("Progress for "+ l_this)});
            loaderInfo.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, function(_e:IOErrorEvent){trace("IOError for "+ l_this)});
            loaderInfo.addEventListener(HTTPStatusEvent.HTTP_STATUS, function(_e:HTTPStatusEvent){trace("HTTPStatus for "+ l_this)});
            ExternalInterface.addCallback("trace", this.trace);
        }
        private var m_params:Object;
        /*! loaderComplete
         * called when the stage has finished loading
         * @param _e : an Event
         */
        private function loaderComplete (_e:Event){
            m_params = new Object;
            for (var i:String in loaderInfo.parameters){
                m_params[i] = loaderInfo.parameters[i];
            }
            trace("loader complete for " + this);
        }
    }
}
```

and when i simply use the html that flash IDE gives me, the firebug console gives me this :

> constructor for Main Pokertales
>
> init for Main Pokertales
>
> Progress for Main Pokertales
>
> loader complete for MainPokertales

but, when I use swiff like this (.js file included in  right after my moo-core.js) :

```
mySwiff = new Swiff("files/main.swf",{
  width:  200,
  height: 150,
  params: {
      wmode: 'opaque',
  },
  vars: {
      myVariableString: 'hello'
  },
  callBacks: {
    load: function() {
      alert("Flash is loaded!");
      console.log("flash is loaded");
      this.trace('hello from flash');
    },
    error: function(){console.log("error!")},
    start: function(){console.log("start!")}
  }
});
console.log(mySwiff);
window.addEvent('domready', function() {
  console.log('dom is ready');
  //document.newElement(mySwiff);/*
  var myCont;
  if (myCont = $('swiffcontainer')){
    mySwiff.inject(myCont,'top');
  };
  //console.log(myCont, mySwiff);
});
```

i only get the two first logs (no progress, no complete, and no load callback...

> Object options=Object instance=Swiff_1251130426079
>
> dom is ready
>
> constructor for Main Pokertales
>
> init for Main Pokertales

so the swf is created, it inits its loaderInfo then stops... anyone got insights on this?

What am I doing wrong here?
OH, and thanks in advance for any help :)

EDIT : as weird as it may seem, the swiff actually fully loads and logs all the way to loader complete, IF the .swf file has been generated less than 10seconds ago... if i hit "publish" in flash IDE and then immediately hit F5 in firefox, I get this log :

> Object options=Object instance=Swiff_1251294375102
>
> dom is ready constructor for Main
>
> Pokertales init for Main Pokertales
>
> Progress for Main Pokertales
>
> loader complete for Main Pokertales
>
> ```
>       start = Swiff.CallBacks.Swiff_1251294375102.start
>
>       myVariableString = hello
>
>       error = Swiff.CallBacks.Swiff_1251294375102.error
>
>       load = Swiff.CallBacks.Swiff_1251294375102.load
> ```

Maybe I'm missing some security/allowDomain issue I don't know? Surely I can't publish & upload a .swf every 10s on my site (productivity would be quite low :) )

EDIT 2 : Ok I am narrowing the problem : the script actually works if i open the html file directly, but stops a init event when called through HTTP (local or distant servers all the same). Is it some domain policy thing I don't know?

Comment: after toying around this, it seems that it works when Security.sandboxType is "localTrusted", and not work when Security.sandboxType is "remote"

Answer (score 1):

I've never used  that particular mootools script (may I recommend SWFObject? ^^), but it seems that its not streaming the SWF, and I vagely remember that as a normal behaviour when using JS script for Flash embedding. I'm not sure there is an actual solution, but one workaround, if you reaaaly need the infoLoader events of your main movie (I personally have never used them) would be to use a small loader.swf to load your main.swf inside it.

Comment: Ok thanks for the input, I'll look into SWFObject.

The fact is I need my ExternalInterface methods available to javascript (i.e my "trace" function) to call them from javascript to ActionScript. I was under the impression those were available only after loaderInfo is complete. I may be wrong.

I'm editing the question since I just found a weeeiiiiiiiird issue.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have solved the problem, though I don't know how...
Among other things, it seems that inserting

```
  mySwiff = $(mySwiff.id);
```

right after the injection of the swiff in the swiffcontainer did the trick... Don't ask me.